# Modifying a docker image that was created from an existing one

Tags: docker

By following a how-to, I've created a new image based on an existing one.
I don´t have the original images' Dockerfile and there are things happening when the container starts that
I can't change - that´s how it seems anyway.

Is there a way to modify the commands in the Dockerfile of the base image?

For example the container runs a bash script when it starts, I want to change this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To answer your specific q: "*the container runs a bash script when it starts, i want to change this*".  Let's assume you want to run `/script.sh` (part of the image) instead of the default, you can instantiate a container using:

```
docker run --entrypoint /script.sh repo/image
```

If `script.sh` isn't part of the image and/or you prefer not having to specify it explicitly each time with `--entrypoint` as above, you can prepare an image that contains and runs your own `script.sh`:

1. Create an empty directory and copy or create `script.sh` in it
2. Create `Dockerfile` with following content:

   ```
   FROM repo/image
   ADD script.sh /
   ENTRYPOINT /script.sh
   ```
3. `docker build -t="myimage" .`
4. `docker run myimage`

Notes:

- When running the container (step 4), it's no longer necessary to specify `--entrypoint` since we have it defaulted in the `Dockerfile`.
- It's really that simple; no need to sign up to docker hub or any such thing (although it's of course recommended in time ;-)

Comment: I think also we need to permission to make file executable.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new Dockerfile in an empty Directory. Start the Dockerfile with

```
FROM repo/image
```

where 'repo/image' is the id of the image your are currently using.

and add your customizations below.

This way you build a new image that is based on another image.

In particular, to change the command that runs at startup, put in a CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT line.

Comment: does this procedure replace the dockerfile of the base image or does it just append something, that´s something i missed here...thx!

Comment: The Dockerfile contains instructions to build an image. `FROM xxx/yyy` in a Dockerfile starts with the image `xxx/yyy` and further customizes it. I think "replace" or "append" doesn't really apply here.

Comment: The way I understand it, a `Dockerfile` is much like a `Makefile`, a series of instructions to build an image.  If your `Dockerfile` includes `ADD` or `COPY` instructions that target files which are already contained in the base image, then the base files do get "replaced" ("layered over" is probably more accurate).

Answer (score 3):

If launching the container with the command from the tutorial fails, your base image most likely introduced an ENTRYPOINT. Any commands you specify for `docker run` will be appended as options to the ENTRYPOINT command. Thus, given an ENTRYPOINT of e.g. `/usr/bin/somescript`,

```
docker run -d --name newguest -p 8080:80 mymod/httpd:v1 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

will cause the container to execute

```
/usr/bin/somescript /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

instead of

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

To get rid of the ENTRYPOINT, use the `--entrypoint` option:

```
docker run --entrypoint "" -d --name newguest -p 8080:80 mymod/httpd:v1 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shell into a running container, modify it, and save the modified container as a new image with:

```bash
docker commit c7e6409a22bf my-new-image
```

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515438/5783745):

```bash
# Run an existing image
docker run -dt existing_image 

# See that it's running
docker ps
# CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS              
# c7e6409a22bf   existing-image   "R"       6 minutes ago        Up 6 minutes

# Shell into it
docker exec -it c7e6409a22bf bash

# Make a new directory for demonstration purposes
# (note that this is inside the existing image)
mkdir NEWDIRECTORY

# Open another terminal tab/window, and save the running container you modified
docker commit c7e6409a22bf my-new-image

# Inspect to ensure it saved correctly
docker image ls
# REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
# existing-image       latest    a7dde5d84fe5   7 minutes ago   888MB
# my-new-image         latest    d57fd15d5a95   2 minutes ago   888MB
```