# intel pin with docker

Tags: docker, intel-pin

i have a pintool that runs normaly with this command:

```
../../../pin -injection child -t obj-intel64/mypintool.so -- obj-intel64/myexcecutable
```

i want in the position of `myexcecutable` to put a [docker program](http://cloudsuite.ch/graphanalytics/) which runs with this command:

```
docker run --rm --net spark-net --volumes-from data \
             cloudsuite/graph-analytics \
             --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 4g \
             --master spark://spark-master:7077
```

when I tried to simply replace the `-- obj-intel64/myexecutable` with the docker command, the pintool started normally but it didn't finish normally.

I believe that my pintool attaches to docker and not in the contained application which is my target.

Do I have to follow a different approach in order to attach correctly my pintool in a program running in a docker container ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a docker expert but running it this way will indeed make pin instrument the docker exec. You need to put pin inside the docker instance and run the executable in the docker instance under pin. That is, command line should look something like this:

```
 docker -run <docker arguments> pin <pin arguments>  --myexecutable <executable arguments>
```

Comment: That's why I did that question, that's the first I've tryed. Docker doesn't let me do it... As I can notice, docker uses containers, but not executables. That's my real problem. I am trying to find the master (server) executable to run it via my pintool! -> http://cloudsuite.ch/graphanalytics/ Here you can see the docker benchmark

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105112/howto-modify-an-docker-image-that-was-created-from-an-existing-one