# How to Edit Docker Image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I did a basic search in the community and could not find a suitable answer, so I am asking here. Sorry if it was asked earlier.

Basically , I am working on a certain project and we keep changing code at a regular interval . So ,we need to build docker image everytime due to that we need to install dependencies from requirement.txt from scratch which took around 10 min everytime.

How can I perform direct change to docker image and also how to configure entrypoint(in Docker File) which reflect changes in Pre-Build docker image

Answer (score 7):

#### There are 4 Steps

1. Start the image you want to edit: `docker run IMAGE`
2. Modify the running image by shelling into it with `docker exec -it <container-id>` (you can get the container id with `docker ps`)
3. Make any modifications (install new things, make a directory or file)
4. In a new terminal tab/window run `docker commit <container-id> my-new-image` (substituting in the container id of the container you want to save)

#### An example

```bash
# Run an existing image
docker run -dt existing_image 

# See that it's running
docker ps
# CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS              
# c7e6409a22bf   existing-image   "R"       6 minutes ago        Up 6 minutes

# Shell into it
docker exec -it c7e6409a22bf bash

# Make a new directory for demonstration purposes
# (note that this is inside the existing image)
mkdir NEWDIRECTORY

# Open another terminal tab/window, and save the running container you modified
docker commit c7e6409a22bf my-new-image

# Inspect to ensure it saved correctly
docker image ls
# REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
# existing-image       latest    a7dde5d84fe5   7 minutes ago   888MB
# my-new-image         latest    d57fd15d5a95   2 minutes ago   888MB
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't edit an image once it's been built.  You always run `docker build` from the start; it always runs in a clean environment.

The flip side of this is that Docker caches built images.  If you had image `01234567`, ran `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`, and got image `2468ace0` out, then the next time you run `docker build` it will see the same source image and the same command, and skip doing the work and jump directly to the output images.  `COPY` or `ADD` files that change invalidates the cache for future steps.

So the standard pattern is

```sh
FROM node:10 # arbitrary choice of language

WORKDIR /app

# Copy in _only_ the requirements and package lock files
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# Install dependencies (once)
RUN yarn install

# Copy in the rest of the application and build it
COPY src/ src/
RUN yarn build

# Standard application metadata
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

If you only change something in your `src` tree, `docker build` will skip up to the `COPY` step, since the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was facing the same, after minor changes, i was building the image again and again.

My old DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.8.0

WORKDIR /app

# Install system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y gcc

# Install project dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

# Don't use terminal buffering, print all to stdout / err right away
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . .
```

so what I did, created a base image file first like this (Avoided the last line, did not copy my code)

```
FROM python:3.8.0

WORKDIR /app

# Install system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y gcc

# Install project dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

# Don't use terminal buffering, print all to stdout / err right away
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```

and then build this image using

```
docker build -t my_base_img:latest -f base_dockerfile .
```

then the final **Dockerfile**

```
FROM my_base_img:latest 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
```

And as my from this image, I was not able to up the container, issues with my copied python code, so you can edit the image/container code, to fix the issues in the container, by this mean i avoided the task of building images again and again.

When my code got fixed, I copied the changes from container to my code base and then finally, I created the final image.